# is js (java script) is enough for the one website? I just one wanna make the one website

Tags: javascript

I know little bit of html, so can I just go with the js becasue I just wanna make the one website. that's it.
expecting the answer of the question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

My interpretation of your question is that you'd like to know if you can simply build your website in JavaScript, without much HTML.

I suggest checking out frameworks like:

- [React](https://reactjs.org), which allow you to build and update your UI from JavaScript.

  React allows you to construct components in JSX with HTML-like syntax, although you can choose not to do so if you'd like.
- [Vue](https://vuejs.org) is another option - a hybrid of React and HTML and requires more use of HTML.

If you'd like to do it without any framework, you can manipulate the DOM through JavaScript too, with APIs like `document.createElement`, `document.appendChild` and `document.textContent`. This approach is generally fragile and cumbersome, so I'd recommend that you pick one of the frameworks above if you aren't too familiar with those APIs.

Finally, I personally feel that learning basic HTML, CSS and JS syntax is a basic step to web development and shouldn't be skipped. It serves as a foundation which helps tremendously in problems you might face using web frameworks, and to understand what's actually going on under the hood.